# How to calculate timeOnPage directly in BigQuery interface?

Tags: google-bigquery

Even though BigQuery is giving us directly the hits (page & event) it does not have the time spent per page (as it's a difference between 2 successive hits given that the pagepath has changed) in order to recalculate the global time spent for a group of pages.

I know i can do it in my data warehouse with a simple copy of my big query table (filter on page and a join on a.hit_number = b.hit_number-1) but i'm expecting to directly calculate it in BigQuery.

Answer (score 1):

yes. it is easily can be done with bigquery's window functions  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#windowfunctions

Answer (score 1):

Hope below simplified example will help

```
select
  user,
  page,
  ts as start,
  CASE WHEN finish = 0 THEN NULL 
    ELSE finish - ts END as duration
from (
  select 
    user,
    page,
    ts,
    LAG(ts, 1, 0) OVER(PARTITION BY user ORDER BY ts DESC) as finish
  from ( -- below is sample data 
    select user, page, type, ts from 
        (select 1 as user, 1 as page, 1 as ts, 'page' as type),
        (select 1 as user, 2 as page, 3 as ts, 'page' as type),
        (select 1 as user, 3 as page, 6 as ts, 'page' as type),
        (select 1 as user, 4 as page, 9 as ts, 'other' as type),
        (select 1 as user, 5 as page, 12 as ts, 'other' as type),
        (select 2 as user, 1 as page, 1 as ts, 'page' as type),
        (select 2 as user, 2 as page, 2 as ts, 'page' as type),
        (select 2 as user, 3 as page, 10 as ts, 'page' as type)
  )
  where type = 'page'
)
order by user, ts
```

Expected output is as below:

```
user    page    start   duration     
1       1       1       2    
1       2       3       3    
1       3       6       null     
2       1       1       1    
2       2       2       8    
2       3       10      null
```

null duration is for last pages

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mikhail, but it's still quite blurred.

Is it something like that ?

```
`SELECT
`visitNumber,
    visitId,
      fullVisitorId,
      hits.hitNumber,
      hits.type,
      hits.time,
      OVER (PARTITION BY visitNumber, visitId, fullVisitorId, hits.hitNumber, hits.type, hits.time) as hits.time2
    FROM ga_sessions_...`
```

How to specify that :
- in partition i'm looking for hits.hitNumber - 1 for hits.type = 'PAGE' only ?
- how to join on the other variable (visitNumber, fullvisitorId, ...) ?

Thanks